# socket.on disconnecttion doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to know if my socket is disconnected or not. In the connection every thing is fine, but I don't know how to disconnect.

Here is the *server.js* for the connection and the client html file.

```
//server.js 

var html = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.html');
    var app = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.end(html);
    });

    app.listen(port); //ecoute sur le numero de port entré en paramétre

    console.log(' ====> Server listening on * : ' + port);
    var io = require("socket.io");

    var io = io.listen(app);

    var count = 0
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.emit('alerte de connexion');
        count ++;
        console.log(count + " utilisateur(s) connecté(s) à la zone de partage ");
    });


//client test.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Zone de Partage</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test de Communication effectué avec succée</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        var socket = io.connect();
                                        socket.on('alerte de connexion', function () {
                                        alert('socket marche trés bien ! ===> voir console ');
                                          });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `socket.on('disconnect')` event, which is triggered whenever client disconnects

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('alerte de connexion');
    count ++;
    console.log(count + " utilisateur(s) connecté(s) à la zone de partage ");

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        //do work
    });
});
```